# React : Add an object into an array

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm a beginner with React, and I would like to add an object into an array.

Here is my code :

```
const initialState =
{
  messages: [],
};



export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_MESSAGE':
      return {
    messages: update(state.messages, {$push: [{text: action.text}]})
  };

  default:
  return state
  }
}
```

And in my component:

```
<ul>{this.props.chat.messages.map((message) =>{ return <li>{message.text}</Link></li> })
```

}

And I get the error:

`Encountered two children with the same key,`[object Object]`. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used.`

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to provide [unique keys](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for each list item. Your messages don't have a key/ID and you need to provide a uniquely generated ID or as a last resort, use the index (which should be avoided as long as possible). The code above can be refactored as:

```
{ this.props.chat.messages.map((message, index) => (<li key={index}>{message.text}</li>) }
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition, Arrays are immutable data.

Following in the best practices, preferred use the $splice method.